# Win 7 Command prompt does't use PATH to find executables

Tags: windows-7, command-line, path

The command prompt cannot find such common commands as `ping`, `ipconfig` etc until I navigate to `system32`. But the `PATH` variable contains `%SystemRoot%\System32\`.

What could be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that the contents of PATH variable are correct, then check the registry:

1. Open regedit.exe
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
3. What's the type of "Path" registry key? If it's not not REG_EXPAND_SZ then this could be the problem.
4. You can change it to REG_EXPAND_SZ by doing this:

   ```
     * Double Click “Path” and copy it’s Data Value “…%SystemRoot%system32;%SystemRoot%; …”
     * Delete the “Path”
     * Create New > Expandable String Value
     * Give “Path” as the name, double click it, and Paste the value copied in the previous step to the “Value Data” field
   ```
5. Close the Regedit window and restart

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Anyway, could you explain the difference?

Comment: They are just different Registry Value Types. It could be that some recently installed program has changed the type to REG_SZ which makes the Path variable unusuable. So if you can recall what you have recently installed then you can test which installer messes it up :)

Comment: But why does REG_SZ type make the Path variable unusable?

Comment: Because then the command prompt interpreter does not replace the %variables% (like %SystemRoot%) variable with its value. Probably you could use REG_SZ type but then you'd have to write out the full paths, i.e. c:\windows\system32 instead of %SystemRoot%\System32\